# How do Americans view the media, especially CNN?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, media

Trump's conflict with the media, especially with CNN, continues...

In a tweet, which was retweeted from the official @POTUS account, Trump [wrote that](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/jul/02/trump-body-slam-cnn-tweet-violence-reporters-wrestlemania):

> #FraudNewsCNN #FNN

Trump also claimed that they are liars.

How do Americans see the media, especially CNN? Do they consider the media, especially CNN, to be liars?  Answers based on polls preferred.

<sub>This question is not about how people think about Trump; it's about how they view the media.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Quinnipiac University Polling Institute did [a national survey](https://poll.qu.edu/national/release-detail?ReleaseID=2456) in April, which in-part assessed trust in the media as a whole, versus trust in Trump.

They summarized their findings as follows:

> American voters disapprove 58 - 37 percent of the way the news media covers Trump. Voters disapprove 65 - 31 percent of the way Trump talks about the media. And voters trust the media more than Trump 57 - 31 percent to tell the truth about important issues.

Check the link for raw numbers, where you can also compare responses by party versus independents.

[The Morning Consult also conducted a poll last December](https://morningconsult.com/2016/12/07/poll-majority-find-major-media-outlets-credible/), which has stats on how individual outlets of the media compare.

> Despite the proliferation of coverage of fake news and historically low opinion of the media, a majority of adults think most cable news networks and major newspapers are credible, according to a Morning Consult poll.
>
> [...]
>
> Television news gets the highest number of people saying they are credible, with major newspapers such as The New York Times not trailing far behind. ABC led all outlets with 67 percent of people saying it is credible, and CNN was top among cable news networks with 60 percent. Sixty-five percent said both CBS and NBC are credible and 55 percent said the same about the more partisan MSNBC and Fox News channels.
>
> [image: chart]

Comment: Am I the only one that is mildly disturbed by the fact that _The Onion_ is even listed there? Well at least Breitbart is just as credible as them. :P

Comment: @Adwaenyth good satire requires a pretty solid grasp of the situation. There's been plenty of research showing that outfits such as the Daily Show  were fairly reputable in the facts that they used to create their satire.

Comment: "American voters disapprove 58 - 37 percent of the way the news media covers Trump". what is 58%? and what is 37%?

Comment: @user1 That means 58% disapprove of how the media covers Trump, for one unspecified reason or another.

Comment: Note the large "incredible" ratings of the major cable news networks, Fox, CNN, and MSNBC. They compare to the Onion. It suggests they have become just as partisan as Breitbart or HuffPo.

Answer (score 2):

**The Mainstream Media**

> Nearly two-thirds of Americans say the mainstream press is full of fake news, a sentiment that is held by a majority of voters across the ideological spectrum.
>
> According to data from the latest Harvard-Harris poll, which was provided exclusively to The Hill, 65 percent of voters believe there is a lot of fake news in the mainstream media.
>
> That number includes 80 percent of Republicans, 60 percent of independents and 53 percent of Democrats. Eighty-four percent of voters said it is hard to know what news to believe online.

According to [The Hill](http://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/334897-poll-majority-says-mainstream-media-publishes-fake-news)

Although that doesn't explicitly state CNN. CNN is certainly a member of the mainstream media.

**CNN Specifically**
CNN is rapidly losing consumer perception as to their brand and is ranked negatively, below Fox News and MSNBC [according to polling by YouGov.](https://today.yougov.com/news/2017/02/27/msnbc-passes-cnn-consumer-perception/) Although this directly doesnt indicate trustworthiness it is bonetheless an indicative factor.

Comment: `YouGov BrandIndex measured CNN, Fox News Channel and MSNBC with its Buzz score, which asks respondents: "If you've heard anything about the brand in the last two weeks, through advertising, news or word of mouth, was it positive or negative?”` So, the question is YouGov is not "do you think bad or good about CNN, Fox News Channel and MSNBC" but *if the people heard something positive or negative*.... uhm... that could easily be someone with broad press coverage who has said one or two (or ten) negative thinks about CNN or MSNBC. Do we have any likely suspect?

Comment: Apart from that, the video also seems irrelevant (unless you can show that people's opinion are actually swayed by it, as opposed to just confirming the existing bias of some).

Comment: Additionally to what @SJuan76 says, but the article about YouGov specifically references a rumor that CNN played pornography instead of news for some period of time.  Of course a poll about "had you heard anything negative" would factor that in, but I assume most people who heard it would dismiss it.  (In much the same way that it's hard for me to imagine a large number of people believing the same about MSNBC or Fox News... political beliefs aside, it doesn't sound credible)